# JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

Не хочет сохранять отношение типа OneToMany с фронта, используя @RequestBody.

**Фронт:**

```
// Будущее название подкатегории
<input type="text" placeholder="Название подкатегории">

// Здесь выбор категории к которой привяжется подкатегория
<select>
    <option value="4">Категория 4</option>
</select>

<button type="submit">Добавить</button>
```

**Запрос**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**category.java**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH })
private List<SubCategory> subCategoryList;
```

**subcategory.java**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH })
@JoinColumn(name = "category")
private Category category;
```

**Бэкенд**: `addSubCategory(@RequestBody SubCategory subCategory)`

При таком раскладе выпадает ошибка при парсинге этого тела запроса [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы пытаетесь строку `"5"` преобразовать в объект `SubCategory`. А маппер вам говорит, что так не умеет. Ему нужен конструктор или специальный десериализер.

Соответственно есть несколько путей:

1. Корректируем json

   ```
   {
        "name":"123",
        "category": {
            "id": 5
        }
   }
   ```
2. Добавляем конструктор

   ```
    private static class Category  {
        public Category(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Category(String id) {
            this.id = Integer.parseInt(id);
        }
    }
   ```
3. Но я так понимаю вы работаете к `Entity` и объекты, не привязанные к БД вам не нужны. Добавим десериализатор, который работает с БД:

   ```
    @JsonComponent
    public class CategoryDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Category> {
        @Autowired
        private CategoryService service;

        @Override
        public Category deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            return service.findById(jsonParser.getIntValue()).orElse(null);
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. Воспользовался десериализатором. А вот вопрос: возможно ли сервис сделать абстрактным и имплементировать репозиторий? Где то я такой подход видел, но выдает ошибку мол не найден бин сервиса при старте...

Comment: @Митяй не понял немного в чем замысел) Можете куда-нибудь пример закинуть? Поле с репозиторием можно через `@Autowired` добавить, если это имелось ввиду)

Comment: @Митяй ой нет, так не стоит делать. Репозиторий никогда не стоит имплементировать куда-либо, он должен существовать как отдельный бин. И сервис cделать абстрактным тоже не выйдет, т.к. абстрактный класс нельзя инициализировать и бином он соответственно тоже не станет.